# Find missing record and return adjacent records SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a requirement to return the adjacent records to a missing record in a sequence in native SQL. If the first entry in the sequence is missing, then only return the next entry. There is no need to look for a missing end in the sequence.

This is running in SQL Server 12.0.2000.8

The structure of the columns in question:

```
BatchId(nvarchar(50), null) 
CreateDate(datetime, null)
UserId(varchar(50), null) 
Batch(varchar(50), null)
```

The last numbers in the BatchId after the " - " determines the sequence. The BatchId correlates with the Batch. When the batch changes the sequence on BatchId should reset to 1.

```
BatchId         CreateDate              UserId      Batch
#########################################################
9K182855 - 1    2017-09-26 17:57:20.977 9K182855    8
9K182855 - 2    2017-09-26 18:20:57.693 9K182855    8
9K182855 - 1    2017-09-27 11:04:46.177 9K182855    9
9K182855 - 2    2017-09-27 11:19:32.990 9K182855    9
```

The query I am using to get data

```
select BatchID, CreateDate, UserId, Batch from Results
where CreateDate > dateadd(day,-2,getdate())
and Batch between 0 and 9
order by UserId, CreateDate, Batch;
```

This is **GOOD** data

```
BatchId         CreateDate              UserId      Batch
#########################################################
4L182855 - 1    2017-09-28 14:04:46.177 4L182855    9
4L182855 - 2    2017-09-28 15:19:32.990 4L182855    9
4L182855 - 3    2017-09-28 16:30:27.953 4L182855    9
4L182855 - 4    2017-09-28 17:57:20.977 4L182855    9
4L182855 - 5    2017-09-28 18:20:57.693 4L182855    9
4L182855 - 1    2017-09-29 11:04:46.177 4L182855    0
4L182855 - 2    2017-09-29 11:19:32.990 4L182855    0
4L182855 - 3    2017-09-29 11:30:27.953 4L182855    0
4L182855 - 4    2017-09-29 11:57:20.977 4L182855    0
4L182855 - 5    2017-09-29 12:00:57.693 4L182855    0
4L182855 - 6    2017-09-29 12:04:46.177 4L182855    0
4L182855 - 7    2017-09-29 12:19:32.990 4L182855    0
4L182855 - 8    2017-09-29 12:30:27.953 4L182855    0
4L182855 - 9    2017-09-29 13:57:20.977 4L182855    0
4L182855 - 10   2017-09-29 14:20:57.693 4L182855    0
```

This is **MISSING** data

```
BatchId         CreateDate              UserId      Batch
#########################################################
4L182855 - 1    2017-09-28 14:04:46.177 4L182855    9
4L182855 - 2    2017-09-28 15:19:32.990 4L182855    9
4L182855 - 4    2017-09-28 17:57:20.977 4L182855    9
4L182855 - 5    2017-09-28 18:20:57.693 4L182855    9
4L182855 - 1    2017-09-29 11:04:46.177 4L182855    0
4L182855 - 2    2017-09-29 11:19:32.990 4L182855    0
4L182855 - 3    2017-09-29 11:30:27.953 4L182855    0
4L182855 - 4    2017-09-29 11:57:20.977 4L182855    0
4L182855 - 5    2017-09-29 12:00:57.693 4L182855    0
4L182855 - 6    2017-09-29 12:04:46.177 4L182855    0
4L182855 - 7    2017-09-29 12:19:32.990 4L182855    0
4L182855 - 8    2017-09-29 12:30:27.953 4L182855    0
4L182855 - 10   2017-09-29 14:20:57.693 4L182855    0
```

The requirement is to return the rows below, they are adjacent to the missing records

```
BatchId         CreateDate              UserId      Batch
#########################################################
4L182855 - 2    2017-09-28 15:19:32.990 4L182855    9
4L182855 - 4    2017-09-28 17:57:20.977 4L182855    9
4L182855 - 8    2017-09-29 12:30:27.953 4L182855    0
4L182855 - 10   2017-09-29 14:20:57.693 4L182855    0
```

I could do this in Python or possibly via the CLR User Defined Functions. However, I am not sure its possible in native SQL. Please enlighten me if it can be so.

Comment: Are missing rows are determined by the `BatchId`?

Comment: How will you handle cases when the first line of the batch is missing? Will you be able to identify cases where the last line of the batch is missing?

Comment: Yes sir, the last number in the BatchId after the " - ". The BatchId should always correlate with the Batch. When the batch changes from 9 to 0 the counter on BatchId should reset to 1. The UserId can differ. I will change the question to reflect your comment. Thank you

Comment: Well the problem is you need to extract the number `##` from batchid  `4L182855 - ##` so you need split the string.

Comment: There are near-duplicates in your data.  For example, the two rows with a `BatchId` having a suffix of "1" have exactly the same `BatchId`.  The rows differ only by the `CreateDate`.  But the `CreateDate` differs for successive rows in the sequence that you have shown.  Therefore, there is no column, or set of columns, that distinguishes the first sequence of five values from the second set of 10 values.  These sequences have to be distinguished, however, to determine whether each one contains gaps.

Comment: @rd_nielsen how about `batch` column?

Comment: The way I would do it in python is split the BatchId string on " - ", get the range of elements in Batch. and determine which items are missing in the range and return the records -1 and +1 from that point. Unsure about here.

Comment: @rreeves what version of sql-server are you using?

Comment: Totally doable in SQL. I'll put something together, but I'm not sure how quickly it will run.

Comment: How do the records become missing?  Maybe there is an audit log which could be referenced to directly return the missing data?

Comment: The client never sends the missing records

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using `stuff()` to truncate the `batchid` to get the batch sequence, and [**`lead()`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213125.aspx) and [**`lag()`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh231256.aspx) to get the values from the previous and next rows for the calculated `BatchSeq`:

```
select s.BatchId, s.CreateDate, s.UserId, s.Batch
from (
  select t.*
    , PrevSeq = lag(x.BatchSeq)  over (partition by Batch order by CreateDate)
    , x.BatchSeq
    , NextSeq = lead(x.BatchSeq) over (order by CreateDate)
  from results t
    cross apply (values (convert(int,stuff(t.batchid,1,charindex('- ',t.batchid)+1,'')))
      ) x (BatchSeq)
  ) s
where BatchSeq - isnull(PrevSeq,0) != 1 
  or (BatchSeq - NextSeq !=-1 and NextSeq != 1)
order by createdate
```

rextester demo: http://rextester.com/ZCBLP37968

returns:

```
+---------------+---------------------+----------+-------+
|    BatchId    |     CreateDate      |  UserId  | Batch |
+---------------+---------------------+----------+-------+
| 4L182855 - 2  | 2017-09-28 15:19:32 | 4L182855 |     9 |
| 4L182855 - 4  | 2017-09-28 17:57:20 | 4L182855 |     9 |
| 4L182855 - 8  | 2017-09-29 12:30:27 | 4L182855 |     0 |
| 4L182855 - 10 | 2017-09-29 14:20:57 | 4L182855 |     0 |
+---------------+---------------------+----------+-------+
```

---

This also works with a missing first record: http://rextester.com/BLAD55913

Comment: You sir are quick on the draw. The where clause is also very nice. More efficient than what I was coming up with. Very nice.

Comment: Very impressive, consider my mind blown. Thank you sir